# How to prevent scrolling on body content and enable scrolling on off-canvas navigation when open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I have implemented a very basic off-canvas navigation(http://blog.tomri.ch/super-simple-off-canvas-menu-navigation/). The only issue I'm having is that you can't scroll the menu, this is especially problematic in mobile landscape mode, where the menu extends below the viewable screen area.

I am wondering if there is a way, when the navigation menu is open, to prevent the content within the `page-wrapper` div from scrolling and enable scrolling in the off-canvas navigation, and, if possible, not show a big ugly scrollbar on the navigation.

**HTML:**

```
<nav id="menu">
    <a href="#menu" class="menu-link"></a>
    <ul>
       <span><a href="#">Title</a></span>
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="page-wrapper">
    Body Content Here
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 13.755em;
    right: -13.755em;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transition: 0.15s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.15s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.15s ease;
    transition: 0.15s ease;
}
    #menu.active {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-13.755em, 0px);
        -moz-transform: translate(-13.755em, 0px);
        -o-transform: translate(-13.755em, 0px);
        -ms-transform: translate(-13.755em, 0px);
        transform: translate(-13.755em, 0px);
    }
.page-wrapper {
       -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
       -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
       -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
       -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
       transform: translate(0px, 0px);
       -webkit-transition: 0.15s ease;
       -moz-transition: 0.15s ease;
       -o-transition: 0.15s ease;
       transition: 0.15s ease;  
}
    .page-wrapper.active {
           -webkit-transform: translate(-13.725em, 0px);
           -moz-transform: translate(-13.725em, 0px);
           -o-transform: translate(-13.725em, 0px);
           -ms-transform: translate(-13.725em, 0px);
           transform: translate(-13.725em, 0px);
    }

.menu-link {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: -50px;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(".menu-link").click(function(){
    $("#menu").toggleClass("active");
    $(".page-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
});
```

Comment: what is off-canvas navigation?

Comment: The navigation is absolutely positioned so that it remains outside the viewable area until it is triggered.

Comment: It's much easier to store state in either the body or html tag.  ```$("html").toggleClass("menu-active");``` with css selectors ```.menu-active .page-wrapper``` and ```.menu-active #menu```.  That way they all stay in sync, and a single class modifies both sets of css properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enable any block level element to scroll you give it `overflow:auto;` & depending on your site/app `height:100%;`. To disable scrolling on the main content there are a few things you can do, but you will have to experiment with them. You could have the nav extend to 100% width of the page, and the area where you see the content is just covered by an invisible element, to block scrolling or just keep scrolling the nav. You could, on click, disable/enable scrolling on the body also, note for best results apply `overflow:hidden;` on `html,body`, it solves some cross browser / ios issues.

Hope this gives you some insight!

Comment: This is a good start and along the lines of what I was thinking. Thank you, now off to experiment!

Comment: with these app like features, you have to think a bit differently in terms of tackling the problem. And don't be afraid to use webkit prefixed things like `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;` for ios, and cubic-bezier for css transition easing (cubic-bezier.com)... it makes all the difference in the world

Comment: One of those cross browser issues is the Firefox on ios, which will continue to scroll unless, like Shan said, you put overflow hidden to the html as well. 

The problem here is that you wont be able to keep the scroll position, it will be at the top after deactivating the menu.

Any way to prevent this from happening without using javascript? Keep the scrolling position where it is? Even if it is with less browser support.

Comment: @AlexandreRosário Did you find a fix for this? I need to be able to retain position. I'm temporarily deactivating scroll of the main body whilst overlays are in view. Once the overlay is closed, the user should remain at the scroll position they were at prior to opening the overlay.

Answer (score 3):

Well you can add to your div container this attributes when te menu is opened

```
.container.active{
 position:fixed;
 width:100%;
}
```

or

```
.container.active{
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

as  @Shan Robertson explain

Or just add a class with those attributes, that would block the main content to scrolll while the side nav is open.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to write external code, just write it in 'afterOpen' settings
'afterOpen': function() { $( "body" ).css( "overflow-y", "hidden" );

Comment: Could you make it a little more clear that you are setting a callback function in Featherlight, as opposed to jQuery or whatever? I also don't see where in the OP this code would fit exactly, but the OP may not have posted all of their code.